# How to search source code across projects in TFS from Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015

How to search source code across projects in TFS? There's no VS 2015 version of TFS Administrators Toolkit in the VS gallery. TfsSearchCode in CodePlex is very old and it's looking for assemblies I don't have. TFS Power Tools doesn't search source code.

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using?

Comment: It's version 2013.

Answer (score 0):

After installing TFS PowerTools, you'll see additional Visual Studio menu options and functions to support finding files under version control by status or wildcard. Just searching files by names.

[image]

If you are using VSTS, there is an extension [Code Search](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms.vss-code-search&workflowId=marketplace#install-pop-up) provides the feature to search code on web access.

Code Search is also available in Team Foundation Server (TFS) "15" Preview and later. Just configure it in the TFS Administration Console:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I am looking for searching code without installing anything on the server side. Find by wildcard searches filenames, not code.

Comment: There is no such extension/plugin on VS by default. You may get the projects from TFS to your workspace, then in VS, hit Ctrl-Shift-F to search the code.